# How to run normal "HelloWorld.java" Java Action using oozie-4.1.0?

Tags: oozie

I'm new here. I'm trying to manage my all actions using oozie actions. can anyone show me a proper example by running simple "HelloWorld.java" using oozie action ?

it's really a great help for me. good and running answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This link is helpful for running an oozie job -> http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/10/executing-oozie-workflow-with-pig-hive.html 
but for sqoop,pig and hive action

Replace this three action in workflow.xml with java action. see this link -> https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action

In the java code, if you are trying to print the output, then it will be there in yarn application log

Comment: I'm trying to run a java code using oozie on oozie-4.1.0

Comment: have you tried running any sample job via oozie workflow?

Comment: yes i already done this excercise before your answer i creates a job with running status but after few hour i got my job suspended. i check logs then it through Error code - E0816. and now i am getting stuck and same thing is happening with my every single job and i don't have any idea what should i do.

Comment: have you checked the yarn application logs for that particular oozie job

Comment: i checked **yarn application -list** but there is nothing

Comment: go to HOST:11000/oozie web console and click on the workflow id and share me the snapshot

Comment: actually, i worked from command line i don't have access to watch web console.

Comment: type on cli below command with the workflow id and print the output
oozie job -oozie http://HOST:PORT/oozie -info WORKFLOW_ID